# Why is JQuery Mobile giving me an "error loading page" on form submission?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

To reproduce my problem:

Go to http://moboscope.appspot.com/x/http://earth911.com/

Fill in the form at the top, eg. "glass" in the first field, and "78722" in the second field.  Hit "Submit".  Note that the page doesn't change and I get a brief "Error loading page" popup.

The popup appears so quickly that it doesn't look like its even trying to contact the web server.

Trying the same thing again has no effect (not even the error message) unless the page is refreshed.

If I try the GET URL that is submitted, it works as expected:

http://moboscope.appspot.com/x/http://search.earth911.com/?what=glass&where=78722

I've looked at the Javascript console and can't see any errors reported there.  What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method attribute of the form is empty, give it the value "get":

```
method="GET"
```

Your form should look like this:

```
<form action="http://moboscope.appspot.com/x/http://search.earth911.com/" method="get">
```

That way it will work fine.